# Swift error: binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two T operands

Tags: swift

I am writing a mutaitin function for Array. I can't compare the array components like below:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func mutFunc() {
        while self[1]>self[2]{

        }
     }
}
```

The Array must is Int type array. I can't even use this way to compare.

```
while Int(self[1])>Int(self[2]){        
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: What should happen if the type of your array elements doesn't happen to be comparable with `>`? Like what if you had a `[AnyObject]`?

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it in Swift 1.2 or before. This is exactly the problem that extension `where` clauses in Swift 2.0 solves. That way, you can extend Array only and exactly insofar as its element type adopts Comparable (or even Int), thus guaranteeing that `>` is defined.

```
extension Array where Element : Comparable {
    // ... your function involving > goes here
}
```